# SAXParseException -- Attribute not allowed; but only in jboss

Tags: xml, jboss, xsd, saxparser

i have a very simple xsd file

```
<xs:element name="SummaryStatus">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="cnt" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="err" type="xs:int" use="optional" default="0"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

which i use to validate this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SummaryStatus cnt="1" />
```

anywawy, the validation itself works when i run it in a unit test, everything works exactly as expected, the validation apparently uses the xml parsers etc. from **com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*** from \Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar

when i deploy the whole thing to jboss, it uses **org.apache.xerces.*** from jboss-4.2.3.GA\lib\endorsed\xercesImpl.jar and i get this exception

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 63; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'cnt' is not allowed to appear in element 'SummaryStatus'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
    at at.apa.commons.webservice.http.xml.JaxbXmlResponseStrategy$NamespaceFilter.startElement(JaxbXmlResponseStrategy.java:188)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
```

my validation/unmarshal code boils down to this

```
            XMLFilter filter = new NamespaceFilter(getXmlns());
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        filter.setParent(xmlReader);
        unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema").newSchema(getSchemaLocation());
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
        filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        InputSource xml = getInputSource();
        filter.parse(xml);
        return (ResponseType)unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
```

where


`getXmlns() = "http://apa.at/powersearch/inputservice/SummaryStatus"
and
getSchemaLocation() =  SummaryStatus.class.getClassLoader().getResource("schema/SummaryStatus.xsd")`

the url to the schema file i get using getResource is valid and can correctly be resolved (i tried opening an input stream on the url and reading the schema while running in jboss and that works -- so the schema is being loaded correctly)

and the filter looks like

```
protected static class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {  
    private final String xmlns;

    public NamespaceFilter(String xmlns) {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(xmlns, localName, qName);
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
            String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(xmlns, localName, qName, atts);
    }           
}
```

i am using this filter because the xml i get from the web service has no xmlns declaration, so i "inject" it manually so i can validate it against the schema -- again this works totally fine (using the com.sun stuff, but fails with the jboss classes)

i tried updating the xercesImpl.jar in my jboss with version 2.0+ from a maven repo but this just results in a bunch of exceptions while starting the server, and i don't really want to start switching out jar files because it might break other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i ended up doing is changing the schema file to

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="SummaryStatus">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="cnt" type="xs:int" use="required"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="err" type="xs:int" use="optional" default="0"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

before the schema element contained an xmlns and targetNamespace declaration, now that it no longer does, it expects the xml elements that i validate against **not** to be in a namespace anyway, and i can just unmarshal the xml with a simple unmarshaller + schema

```
unmarshaller = getJaxbContext().createUnmarshaller();
        if(getRequest().isResponseStrict()) {
            unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());
        }
        return (ResponseType)unmarshaller.unmarshal(getXmlInputStream());
```